# Understanding Powershell: example - Convert JSON to CSV

Tags: powershell

I've read several posts (like [Convert JSON to CSV using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594860/convert-json-to-csv-using-powershell)) regarding using PowerShell to CSV.  I have also read that it is relatively poor form to use the pipe syntax in scripts -- that it's really meant for command line and can create a hassle for developers to maintain over time.

Using this sample JSON file...

```
[
    {
        "a":  "Value 1",
        "b":  20,
        "g":  "Arizona"
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 2",
        "b":  40
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 3"
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 4",
        "b":  60
    }
]
```

...this code...

```
((Get-Content -Path $pathToInputFile -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json) | Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

...creates a file containing CSV as expected.

```
"a","b","g"
"Value 1","20","Arizona"
"Value 2","40",
"Value 3",,
"Value 4","60",
```

This code...

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $pathToInputFile -Raw
$psObj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content
Export-Csv -InputObject $psObj -LiteralPath $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

...creates a file containing nonsense:

```
"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"4","4","4","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"
```

It looks like maybe an object definition(?).
What is the difference?  What PowerShell nuance did I miss when converting the code?

The answer to [Powershell - Export a List of Objects to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237405/powershell-export-a-list-of-objects-to-csv) says the problem is from the `-InputObject` option causing the object, not it's contents, to be sent to Export-Csv, but doesn't state how to remedy the problem without using the pipe syntax.  I'm thinking something like `-InputObject $psObj.contents`.  I realize that's not a real thing, but I `Get-Members` doesn't show me anything that looks like it will solve this.

Comment: `-InputObject` binds to _each object passed through the pipeline_, it's not meant to be used like what you're doing on your second example.

Comment: OK.  Is it possible to solve this problem without using pipes?

Comment: The cmdlet is built to work with the pipeline, the _`begin` block_ is the one that captures the "Headers" of the first object passed through then it _process_ each pipeline object. This is based on assumptions but I have a feeling that's how it works.

Comment: If you try something like this: `$json.ForEach({ConvertTo-Csv -InputObject $_})` you would see that each object generates a new set of _"Headers"_ based on the object's properties.

Comment: I can confirm that the schema of the CSV matches that of the first object.  That's actually the larger problem I'm trying to solve.  Looks like I'll use pipes.  thanks.

Comment: Here you have 2 examples of how you can solve your problem. Someone asked something very similar not long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70484662/powershell-export-csv-missing-columns/70484836#70484836 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant as an answer but just to give you a vague representation of what `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` are doing and to help you understand why `-InputObject` is meant to be bound from the pipeline and should not be used manually.

```
function ConvertTo-Csv2 {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Object] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $isFirstObject = $true
        filter Normalize {
            if($_ -match '"') { return $_.Replace('"','""') }
            $_
        }
    }

    process {
        if($isFirstObject) {
            $headers = $InputObject.PSObject.Properties.Name | Normalize
            $isFirstObject = $false
            [string]::Format('"{0}"', [string]::Join('","', $headers))
        }

        $values = foreach($value in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties.Value) {
            $value | Normalize
        }
        [string]::Format('"{0}"', [string]::Join('","', $values))
    }
}
```

As we can observe, there is no loop enumerating the `$InputObject` in the [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) of this function, yet, because of how this block works, each object coming from the pipeline is processed and converted to a *Csv string representation of the object*.

> Within a pipeline, the `Process` block executes once for each input object that reaches the function.

If instead, we attempt to use the `InputObject` parameter from the function, the object being passed as argument will be **processed only once**.

> Calling the function at the beginning, or outside of a pipeline, executes the Process block once.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading about and experimenting with the BEGIN-PROCESS-END pattern in PowerShell has been rather enlightening.  Huge boost to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Get-Members doesn't show me anything that looks like it will solve this

### Get-Member

It's because how you pass values has different behavior.

The pipeline enumerates values, it's almost like a `foreach($item in $pipeline)`. Passing by Parameter skips that

Here I have an **array** of 3 letters.

```
$Letters = 'a'..'c'
```

I'm getting different types

```
Get-Member -InputObject $Letters
# [Object[]]

# [char]
$letters | Get-Member
```

### Processed for each item

```
$letters | ForEach-Object { 
    "iteration: $_"
}
```

```
iteration: a
iteration: b
iteration: c
```

Compare to

```
ForEach-Object -InputObject $Letters { 
    "iteration: $_"
}
```

```
iteration: a b c
```

### Detecting types

Here's a few ways to inspect objects.

using [ClassExplorer](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ClassExplorer)

```
PS> ($Letters).GetType().FullName
PS> ($Letters[0]).GetType().FullName  # first child

    System.Object[]
    System.Char

PS> $Letters.count
PS> $Letters[0].Count

    3
    1

$Letters.pstypenames -join ', '
$Letters[0].pstypenames -join ', '

    System.Object[], System.Array, System.Object
    System.Char, System.ValueType, System.Object
```

Tip: `$null.count` always returns 0. It does not throw an error.

```
if($neverExisted.count -gt 1) { ... }
```

### Misc

> I have also read that it is relatively poor form to use the pipe syntax in scripts

This is not true, Powershell is designed around piping objects.

Tip: `$null.count` always returns 0. It does not throw an error.

Maybe They were talking about

### Example2: slow operations

Some cases when you need something fast, the overhead to `Foreach-Object` over a `foreach` can be an issue. It makes it so you have to use some extra syntax.

If you really need speed, you should probably be calling dotnet methods anyway.

### Example1: Piping when you could use a parameter

I'm guessing they meant piping a variable in cases where you can pass parameters?

```
$text = "hi-world"

# then
$text | Write-Host 

# vs
Write-Host -InputObject $Text
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty new to PowerShell.  I don't understand what's happening in those two examples.  That looks exactly opposite what I'm seeing with `Export-CSV`.  Your example appears to show that using `-InputObject` causes the content, not the object (wrapper) to be passed in and the pipe is passing the object.  I could test and inspect the objects, but your code throws an error.